# Using optim() in R to reproduce results of Fisher's book about spherical data

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to reproduce results from "statistical analysis of spherical data".
I want to calculate spherical median (you can see http://www.jstor.org/stable/2345577 for the formula, equation 1, I don't know how to write it here correctly).
I use the B1 dataset of the book :

```
lat1=c(-26.4,-32.2,-73.1,-80.2,-71.1,-58.7,-40.8,-14.9,-66.1,-1.8,-52.1,-77.3,-68.8,-68.4,
   -29.2,-78.5,-65.4,-49,-67,-56.7,-80.5,-77.7,-6.9,-59.4,-5.6,-62.6,-74.7,-65.3,-71.6,
   -23.3,-74.3,-81,-12.7,-75.4,-85.9,-84.8,-7.4,-29.8,-85.2,-53.1,-38.3,-72.7,-60.2,-63.4,
   -17.2,-81.6,-40.4,-53.6,-56.2,-75.1)

long1=c(324,163.7,51.9,140.5,267.2,32,28.1,266.3,144.3,256.2,83.2,182.1,110.4,142.2,246.3,222.6,247.7,
    65.6,282.6,56.2,108.4,266,19.1,281.7,107.4,105.3,120.2,286.6,106.4,96.5,90.2,170.9,199.4,118.6,
    63.7,74.9,93.8,72.8,113.2,51.5,146.8,103.1,33.2,154.8,89.9,295.6,41.0,59.1,35.6,70.7)

library('sphereplot')
B1=data.frame(long=long1,lat=lat1)
a=sph2car(B1$long,B1$lat)
x=a[,1]
y=a[,2]
z=a[,3]
```

I first check the data :

```
sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)

data1=data.frame(x,y,z)

median.direction <- function(par, data1) {
sum(acos(par[1]*data1[,1]+par[2]*data1[,2]+par[3]*data1[,3]))
}

median.direction2=optim(par=c(0,0,0), fn=median.direction, data1=data1)    
result1=car2sph(median.direction2$par[1],median.direction2$par[2],median.direction2$par[3])

result1
```

"For the data (set Bl) of Example 5.1, the spherical median
direction is (lat. 78.9°, long. 98.4°)."

I don't know where is my error :

must I use colatitude with sph2car?
Does optim perform well with the warnings ?

EDIT :

[image]

Comment: What package contains the `sph2car` function?  I probably could look it up, but consider adding your `library` statement to your post.

Comment: The package is `sphereplot`

Comment: The immediate problem is that the argument to `acos()` exceed 1, so `NaN` is returned, therefore the minimiser can't reasonasbly be expected to work. Without full access to the original paper, I can't see why you're coming across this problem, perhaps `par` should be constrained to sum to 1?

Comment: Please provide the article reference- I'm not going to slog thru 500 pages of the online issue.

Comment: Spherical Medians,N. I. Fisher,Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological), Vol. 47, No. 2 (1985), pp. 342-348

sph2car is from sphereplot.

Comment: From the book : " The sample spherical median is an estimate of the population spherical median. Let X be a random vector from the population under study, and a an arbitrary direction, and let 0a = arc cos (X'a), the angular deviation of X from a. The spherical median is the direction a for which the average value of 0a is minimum. By way of comparison, the mean direction is the direction for which the average value of cos 0a is minimum."

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, it's hard to see how the median latitude is +79° when all of the latitudes in the dataset are < 0. So either there's a typo in your question, or there's a mistake in the textbook.

Second, your data is concentrated (more or less) near one of the poles. In this situation your ability to estimate *longitude* is inherently compromised. Consider the extreme case where all the data was at latitude -90°. Then the median latitude would be exactly -90°, but we would know nothing about the median longitude. So your problem with the optimization is that longitude has a "shallow minimum" (in this dataset). That is, there are many longitudes which come pretty close to minimizing your objective function. This is a problem because most optimizers use a local minimizer - they seek minima in the objective function *close to the initial estimates*. Consequently, the answer you get will depend on your starting point.

Third, given the situation above, you would be better off using a more robust optimizer (IMO). In the example below I use `nloptr(...)` from the `nloptr` package. It's a bit more difficult to use, but gives results less sensitive to the initial estimates.

To demonstrate the problem, the code below runs the minimization 100 times, each time with a randomly chosen starting point, and plots the data and the 100 "minima".

```
library(sphereplot)
library(nloptr)
f <- function(par, data1) {
  sum(acos(par[1]*data1[,1]+par[2]*data1[,2]+par[3]*data1[,3]))
}
opts <- list(algorithm="NLOPT_GN_ISRES",xtol_rel=1.0e-6, maxeval=10000)
# set up the plot
rgl.sphgrid()
points3d(x,y,z, col="red",size=5)

set.seed(1)    # for reproducibility
# 100 initial estimates, randomly distributed on the sphere
N <- 100
xyz.init <- sph2car(long=sample(-180:180,N),lat=sample(-90:90,N))
get.median <- function(i) {
  md     <- nloptr(x0=xyz.init[i,],eval_f=f,
                   lb=c(-1,-1,-1), ub=c(1,1,1),
                   data1=data1, opts=opts)
  xyz    <- md$solution
  lines3d(c(0,xyz[1]),c(0,xyz[2]),c(0,xyz[3]),col="green",lwd=2)
  median <- car2sph(xyz[1],xyz[2],xyz[3])
  cat(".")     # cheap and dirty progress bar...
  return(median)
}  
sph.med  <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(xyz.init),get.median))
colMeans(sph.med)
#       long        lat     radius 
#  92.314309 -77.361522   0.998315
```

[image]

You can see that the optimizations create an envelope (cone) of estimates for the "median". The average of all these estimates is pretty close to the result in the book (with the exception of the sign of latitude).

It's worth noting that, in spite of using a maximum of 10,000 iterations, the optimizations generally do not converge!!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. To have a good estimation of the spherical median, could we take the spherical mean as initial value ? Then, calculate confidence cone with the book's formula.

I calculated median direction 4 times with the xyz.init values using nloptr and constroptim. Then I calculated standard deviation for each test on the 100 values. For optim, results didn't change from one run to another unlike nloptr.

Comment: Here are my results : Optim : 
    long          lat       radius 
27.179225899 14.469373433  0.009143291
27.531615252 14.482161030  0.009140174
27.531615252 14.482161030  0.009140174 
27.531615252 14.482161030  0.009140174 


nloptr
     long          lat       radius 
40.141207976  5.700448752  0.005895856
35.707873353  5.903092235  0.00687911
31.001710584  5.295622086  0.006852825 
35.175373208  5.771591144  0.005805983